# Series ending with the trivial group

Tags: group-theory, set-theory

I'm interested in the following seemingly simple question. When we define the composition series or derived series of solvable groups we state that they have to end with the trivial group. Does this usually mean that the corresponding sequence must be finite? Are there cases when we also admit the transfinite sequences (whose ordinal just has the maximal element)? Thanks in advance.

Comment: For a group to be soluble the chain has to terminate at the trivial subgroups in finitely many steps. If you want to extend to transfinite ordinals, then you're looking at a generalised notion of solubility, not solubility itself.

Comment: A composition series must be finite by definition. As for derived series, there is a theorem which states that a group is solvable if and only if the derived series reaches the trivial group after a finite number of steps. But we can also consider the transfinite derived series though, and if it reaches the trivial group then the group is called hypoabelian.

Comment: I am not a group theorist, but I believe that usually, when talking about solvable groups, this implies solvable of finite rank. It certainly makes sense to define solvable groups of transfinite ordinal rank, but you should not expect all results known about solvable groups to work in the infinite rank case. Same with composition series --- the usual convention is that they are finite.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: The usual definition is that we must reach {$e$} within a finite number of steps. Moreover, most of the important properties for solvable groups refer to finite groups (such as the Hall theorem) , in which case it is obvious that {$e$} is reached in a finite number of steps or not at all.

Comment: @tomasz You should not use the word "rank", and rather "length"; for solvable groups "rank" is widely used for unrelated meanings (look for "solvable groups of finite rank"). Beware that hypoabelian is not a property stable under taking quotients: indeed it's satisfied by free groups (hence does **not** imply amenable), as they are residually nilpotent.

Comment: @YCor: I see. Yes, I guess it makes sense. Sorry about the confusion regarding terminology. :) It just seems natural to call an ordinal invariant a rank.